# MySQL Select 1000 records randomly when Primary key is a string

Tags: mysql, random

I have a table with 200k records and I want to have 1000 rows randomly to work on.

The primary key is something like this

> 000279a4-3214-4f9c-93c3-168634f4548a

I saw this question but PK is a number in there, so does not work for me

[MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use order by rand()  and limit 1000

```
select * 
from my_table  
order by rand()  
limit  1000
```